# Spring Boot Cors behind reverse-proxy on non-default port

Tags: spring, docker, nginx, cors

My application has a backend built with Spring Boot, and a frontend web application built with Angular and served by nginx.
Nginx is configured to reverse-proxy requests to /api/ to the backend :

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://back:8080;
}
```

If nginx is running on the default port (80), I can access my application at http://myserver/ without issues. XHR calls to http://myserver/api/some/REST/resource work perfectly.

If I change nginx to listen to some other port (randomly : 9043), then all XHR calls fail with an error "Invalid CORS request". Which is unexpected, because only my frontend application is making calls to the API, and thanks to the reverse-proxy this API is served on the same host as the javascript files.

For it to function, I need to add this to my Spring application :

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Value("${url.base:''}")
    private String urlBase;

    @Value("${cors.allowed.origins:[]}")
    private String[] allowedOrigins;

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping(urlBase + "/**")
                        .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
                        .allowedMethods("*");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and then set `cors.allowed.origin`s to `http://myserver:9043/` in my configuration.

This works, but it is not practical if I'm going to :

- make the hostname and/or port dynamic (port is derived from the branch name during CI build, then the containers are deployed to a rancher cluster)
- hide the nginx behind a load-balancer (= another level of reverse-proxying)

Would there be a solution to fix this by doing any of the following :

- Have spring boot to ignore the port number when validating CORS requests ?
- Have nginx tweak the contents of the proxied request so that CORS validation by Spring succeeds ?

**EDIT :** some more details and example :

The services are dockerized :

- Frontend : nginx listens on port 80 inside the container, docker exposes it on the host as port 9043
- Backend : spring boot listens on 8080. The port is not exported by Docker, so it is only accessible from the frontend container, which has a link to the backend container.

It only works if the frontend is exposed to the outside world on port 80...

Comment: Even if the host is the same, as you've seen, you'll need CORS headers if the front end and back end are on different ports.

Comment: Have you tried to map your endpoint using the property "server.address"? If I'm not wrong if you define your endpoint this will be used by cors and you would have the port with it.

Comment: @lbndev ¿Did you solve this issue? I am stuck with a similar one (it only happens with Chrome, not with Firefox, weird)

Comment: @PabloLozano : no :( Eventually, I worked around it on the infrastructure (using traefik LB + wildcard DNS) so that I'm always using port 80 (or 443). But the question remains valid and open.

Comment: @lbndev I solved it by adding to the proxy configuration `proxy_set_header Origin "";`. It seems that this header was checked by Spring (the header was not added by Firefox and that why it worked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two http header in reverse request:

X-Forwarded-Proto

X-Forwarded-Port

to indecate the origin proto and ports (match the origin request).

see more:   https://moi.vonos.net/java/spring-forward/

Comment: Actually, X-Forwarded-Host can also be an issue. I'm accepting this answer as it provides a valid solution for port and scheme (proto) when the reverse-proxy also performs SSL termination. Thanks a lot ! :)